# ListViewItem does not Stretch

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have a probleme with the ListViewItem, I define the style like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
           <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
           <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
           <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
     </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And the result is:

[image: SnappedImage]

How can I do to stretch ListViewItems ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the ItemContainerStyle but the control that I put into the ListView.

The border doest not fit ListViewItem, to solve the problem I set the width to 280 px (320 - 20 * 2, Snapped ViewState)